# Shell script to find and count total number of characters in all the files

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, find

How can I make a script that finds every file in your home directory that is less than 3 days old and then gets a count of the total number of characters in all of these files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simple:

```
find ~/ -mtime -3 -exec cat {} + | wc -c
```

The above sends counts each character in each file to `wc` which counts them.

If the files are big, the above would involve of a lot of reading from disk.  If would be much more efficient to simply add the sizes of the files.  Methods for getting the size of a file vary among Unix versions.  If your system supports a linux-style `stat` command, however, the following command will work:

```
find . -mtime -3 -type f -exec stat -c%s {} + | awk '{total+=$1} END{print total}'
```

In the above, `stat -c%s` returns the size of each file and `awk` adds them up and reports on the total.  This eliminates the need to read fully each file.

Answer (score 2):

With [`find`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/find.1), [`cat`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/cat.1) and [`wc`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/wc.1):

```
find ~ -type f -mtime -3 -exec cat {} + | wc -c
```

- `-mtime` checks for modification times. Depending on your OS and filesystem, the creation time is not easy to get. Modification time is a reasonable compromise. `-3` means less than 3 days (as opposed to `+3`). Actually, 72 hours.
- `-type f` - restricting ourselves to regular files.
- `-exec cat {} +` - call `cat` on each of the matching files,
- `wc -c`: print the count of characters. Since we have a combined output from all the `cat`s, this is the total.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
find ./ -type f -mtime -3 -exec wc -c {} \; | perl -lane 'BEGIN {$total=0}; $total+=$F[0]; END {print $total}'
```

Examples

```
❮njia@mb-125:~/src/ansible/roles❯➤ find ./ -type f -mtime -3 -exec wc -c {} \;
12288 ./base/tasks/.check_glibc.yml.swp
185 ./base/tasks/check_glibc.yml
❮njia@mb-125:~/src/ansible/roles❯➤ find ./ -type f -mtime -3 -exec wc -c {} \; |    perl -lane 'BEGIN {$total=0}; $total+=$F[0]; END {print $total}'
12473
```

Comment: my solution give you total number of characters of ALL files, not a number for each individual file.